# Como imprimir o segundo valor de uma array?

Tags: php

Tenho essa array e quero colocar na tela a string "Banana".

```
$frutas = array (
"frutas" => array("a"=>"Laranja", "b"=>"Banana", "c"=>"Maçã"),
"numeros" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
"buracos" => array("primeiro", 5 => "segundo", "terceiro")
);
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você tem um *array* de *arrays*. Você sabe trabalhar com *arrays*? Porque não ficou muito claro exatamente qual é o problema. Você que saber apenas como acessa um valor em específico? Você já leu a [documentação sobre *array*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: Não, não sei, estou estudando, posso fazer essa pergunta aqui ou é simples de mais?

Comment: Pode, sem problemas. Só perguntei por ser difícil inferirmos o nível de conhecimento de quem pergunta e quando não fica tão claro o que está sendo perguntado, fica confuso. Você cita o *segundo valor* e depois fala que precisa de um valor de um *array* associativo. Isso não faz muito sentido porque o PHP não garante a ordem de um *array* associativo, então o *segundo valor* poderia variar. Mas sim, sinta-se a vontade para criar uma pergunta sempre que precisar.

Comment: Então não posso pegar exatamente o segundo valor? Legal, aprendi mais uma coisa, vlw.

Comment: Como posso te enviar uma duvida que eu tenho diretamente?

Comment: Nesse caso, *banana* seria o valor associado à chave *b* do *array* que está associado à chave *frutas* de `$frutas`, não necessariamente o *segundo valor* (visualmente é o segundo, mas não necessariamente na memória).

Comment: Pode entrar no [chat Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples assim:

```
echo $frutas["frutas"]["b"];
```

Comment: Obrigado, estou começando agora, fico até com vergonha de tão simples.